# First build with Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm running builds with AzureDevops piplines. When I'm creating new pipline I'm not queueing it and just saving. If CI trigger is selected pipline will run if anything is checked in.

But on the very first run/chack-in pipline will be liked (associated) to ALL check-ins (changesets/commits) that happened before the current one and to all workitems of those chack-ins.

This behaviour is not desired for me. Is there a way to disable it?

On all subsequent check-ins build will be associated only with the one that triggered the pipline. And this is what I want for the first build as well, for it to be associated only with the chack-in that triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what's happening, it's hard to provide advice.  It could also behave differently if you're using Git or TFSVC variants.  Here's a few things to try:

1. Disable the CI trigger, do your first check-in, then re-enable the trigger.  That might skip the change-set and work item affiliation one time.
2. Delete the offending build after it runs or do the laborious task of manually deleting all links in it.
3. If you're using Git, you can also limit the CI trigger by using a Pull Request with Squash merge.  This will consolidate the commits down to one.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that I’m using TFVC. Didn’t try build with git yet, but I will. And yes I can perform some actions to run the build first time and then reconfigure to run as I wish. But I was wandering if there is a proper method to achieve this without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the way to disable it. It would compare previous run, then include all changesets between them. So, for first run, it must includes all previous changesets.

You may create a new branch for a folder, then configure build for that branch. [Learn about branching strategies for Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and how to select an effective strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=azure-devops)